# What is the one sound that fills the gaps?

Tags: riddle

Because I was ____ from using the ____, I took a break, leant back and ____ a ____ wing ____.

Comment: Because I was _New_ from using the _Knew_, I took a break, leant back and _Knew_ a _New_ wing _Knew_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sound is:

> **SAW**, and its homophone equivalents...

This satisfies the sentence like so:

> Because I was **SORE** from using the **SAW**, I took a break, leant back and **SAW** a [**SAW**-wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw-wing) **SOAR**.
>
>  In other words, because you had some aches and pains from using your woodworking tools, you had a rest, looked up at the sky, and witnessed a saw-wing bird coasting on the breeze...

Comment: Why am I not suprised you answered it? Congratulations.

Comment: fnj naq fber ner ubzbcubarf?

Comment: @SteveV Certainly in the UK they are usually considered so, although as with many instances like this I'm sure there are regional differences in pronunciation, especially in the US :)

Comment: Definitely not the same sound to my Canadian ear

Comment: @Jeffrey (and others across the pond!) In the UK a lot of accents would pronounce 'ORE' as 'AW', without really emphasising the 'R' sound in the spelling. At the same time, many UK accents would *heavily* pronounce the 'R' (e.g. Bristol, Dorset, Cornwall...) so there's definitely nothing universal about it even over here! :)